# How to Check Dates Between DATES in SQL ? if Checin and Check out Dates are Between SeasonStart and SeansonEndDate return 1 Otherwise return 0

Tags: sql

```
@CheckInDate DATE TIME = '15/12/2010',  
@CheckOutDate DATETIME = '18/12/2010'  


SeasonStartDate DATETIME = '13/12/2010'
SeasonEndDate DATE TIME =' 20/12/2010'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CASE
 WHEN @CheckInDate BETWEEN SeasonStartDate AND SeasonEndDate
  AND @CheckOutDate BETWEEN SeasonStartDate AND SeasonEndDate
  THEN 1
 ELSE 0
END
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're guaranteed that there's no time travel allowed (In/Out and Start/End are in the correct order):

```
CASE WHEN @CheckInDate >= SeasonStartDate and @CheckOutDate <= SeasonEndDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```